# HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous

Tags: hibernate

In an Hibernate 5 project, I’m getting the following warning during startup:

`[org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@53ec41aa`

What causes this, and how can I avoid it?

The application is running fine; however, I wish to reduce the amount of messages, especially warning-like ones, that an application (even at `INFO` loglevel) throws at normal startup.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, there no errors, the process just stopped there. This happens when some process is currently using the database, when you try to regenerate the tables.

So basically just kill your application

Comment: No, this happens on startup.

Comment: Yes i know it happens on startup, because there is a process using the database

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Unless somebody else has the same issue when database has been shut it down

Comment: No, the application that is in the process of being started is the only thing accessing the database. It’s on an isolated test system with a local DB.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just an informational statement to let you Hibernate has changed how it maps objects. You probably don't need to worry about it, but you could configure the hibernate logging level to WARN or higher to prevent it, but, personally, I think logging everything at INFO level or higher is a good idea.

log4j.xml:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate">
    <level value="warn"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: Nah, I agree, keeping it at INFO is a good idea. But thanks anyway. But normally there has to be a way to acknowledge such messages so they don’t show up every time…